# How can I implement INotifyPropertyChanged in WPF with MVP pattern

Tags: c#, wpf

Good morning everyone, I have a sensor model class that, when the state changes, starts a timer that measures random values ​​at intervals. How can I change the measured values ​​on the main form with the same interval?

**This is my window xaml markup**

```
<ListBox Width="100" Name="Lst" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="Lst_OnSelectionChanged"/>
<Label Width="244" Style="{StaticResource SideText}" x:Name ="LavalIntervalValue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="215,18,0,344" Height="40"/>
<Label Width="244" Style="{StaticResource SideText}" x:Name ="LabelIdValue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="215,73,0,289" Height="40"/>
<Label Width="244" Style="{StaticResource SideText}" x:Name ="LabelStateValue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="215,130,0,232" Height="40"/>
<Label Width="244" Style="{StaticResource SideText}" x:Name ="LabelMeasuredValue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="215,188,0,174" Height="40" />
<Label Width="186" Style="{StaticResource MainText}" Content="Interval" x:Name ="LabelInterval" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="11,18,663,344" Height="40"/>
<Label Width="187" Style="{StaticResource MainText}" Content="Id" x:Name ="LabelId" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,73,663,289" Height="40"/>
<Label Width="186" Style="{StaticResource MainText}" Content="State" x:Name ="LabelState" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="11,130,663,233" Height="39"/>
<Label Width="186" Style="{StaticResource MainText}" Content="Measured Value" x:Name ="LabelMeasured" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="11,188,663,175" Height="39"/>
```

**This is my model**

```
public class Sensor:IObservable
{
    private int _measuredValue;
    private List<IObserver> _observers = new List<IObserver>();
    private IMeasuringState _state = new SimpleState();

    public Sensor(int measuringInterval, SensorType sensorType, int uniqueId)
    {
        MeasuringInterval = measuringInterval;
        SensorType = sensorType;
        UniqueId = uniqueId;
    }


    [JsonIgnore]
    public IMeasuringState MeasuringState
    {
        get => _state;
        set
        {
            if (value!=null)
            {
                _state = value;
              
            }
            NotifyObservers();
        }
    }

    public int UniqueId { get; }

    public int MeasuredValue
    {
        get => _measuredValue;
        set
        {
            _measuredValue = value;
            NotifyObservers();
        }
    }
    public SensorType SensorType { get; }

    public int MeasuringInterval { get; }

    public void ChangeState()
    {
        MeasuringState.Handle(this);
        MeasuringState.StartMeasure(this);
    }
}
```

**Calibration state**

```
public void StartMeasure(Sensor sensor)
{
    _calibrationValue = 0;
    _timer = new Timer(SetCalibration, sensor, 0, 1000);
}

public void Handle(Sensor sensor)
{
    _timer.Dispose();
    sensor.MeasuringState = new WorkState();
}

private void SetCalibration(object obj)
{
    var sensor = obj as Sensor;
    sensor.MeasuredValue = ++_calibrationValue;
}
```

**This is my interface that I implemented in my main window**

In property I set my label content value with presenter.

```
public interface IMainWindowView
{
    List<string> SensorsType { get; set; }
    int SelectedSensor { get; set; }
    int MeasuredValue { get; set; }
    string State { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    int MeasuringInterval { get; set; }

    event EventHandler<EventArgs> OpenFile;

    event EventHandler<StateEventArgs> DeleteSensorById;

    event EventHandler<EventArgs> SaveFile;

    event EventHandler<EventArgs> SelectedItem;


    event EventHandler<StateEventArgs> ChangeStateSensor;


    event EventHandler<EventArgs> OpenAddWindow;
    void ShowWarning(string message);
}
```

Comment: Provide some sample code. It will help you to get answers quickly.

Comment: Do you really mean MVP? If you don't already realise this, pretty much every commercial team uses MVVM. You will probably just get MVVM solutions. How does your implementation of MVP work?

Comment: Also. Your description is a bit confusing. You're capturing random values. You then want to change them? You mean just edit a list of numbers? I don't follow what you mean by "with the same interval".

Comment: I already answered you (https://www.cyberforum.ru/wpf-silverlight/thread2686724.html): MVP can be implemented in WPF application.
But, by doing so, you yourself will create many unnecessary problems.
And these problems will not be WPF specific, so solving them will be difficult to find.

You have just started creating your application, I highly recommend learning MVVM and using it for WPF applications.

Comment: I was told to do on MVP